# date picker displayed when text box is focused

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am just getting into android apps and now trying to  work with an interface that allows the user to enter date into a text box. The date dialog should only display  when a text box is focused.After a date is selected from the dialog, it will be displayed in the text box.  The problem now is the date dialog is displayed even the text box is not focused. Can someone help me to figuring out my problem? Thank.

**TimeSheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtdate"
        android:layout_x="131dp"
        android:layout_y="192dp"
        android:hint="Touch here to select a date"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**TimeSheet.java**

```
package com.example.project.project;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.project.project.API.TimeSheetAPI;
import com.example.project.project.database.MyDatabaseHelper;



public class TimeSheet extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner,spinner2;
    private Button btnSaved;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private TimeSheetAPI ts;






    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timesheet);
        ts=new TimeSheetAPI(this);  
    }


    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        EditText txtDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        txtDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
            {
                if(hasFocus)
                {
                    DateDialog dialog=new DateDialog(v);
                    FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    dialog.show(ft,"DatePicker");
                }
            }

    });
    }
```

**DateDialog.java**

```
package com.example.project.project;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by tongws on 9/14/2015.
 */

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    EditText txtdate;


   public DateDialog(View view)
    {
        txtdate=(EditText)view;
    }


    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year, int month, int day)
    {
         String date=day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
        txtdate.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your layout code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `EditText` has been focused once the activity started. To clear default focus on `EditText`, add focus to the parent layout. This can be done by adding this line of code into your parent view.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

For example,

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtdate"
    android:layout_x="131dp"
    android:layout_y="192dp"
    android:hint="Touch here to select a date"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks..is it possible for the user to re-enter the date again if he selects the wrong date?

Comment: Sure, you can hide the date dialog once the `EditText` was out of focus

Comment: Can you provide with some example?

Comment: @Hoo I don't think you need to add extra coding, you can just dismiss the dialog and click the `EditText` again to submit new date